# CSS won't work with Django

Tags: html, css, django, web

My HTML displays but the CSS doesn't. I'm in development mode and running the django dev runserver.

```
 STATICFILES_DIRS = ("C:/Users/user/site/sitemain/static",)
 STATIC_ROOT= '' STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 MEDIA_ROOT= '' MEDIA_URL=''
```

link in HTML is: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css href="{{ STATIC_URL}}/base.css" />` Tenplate is base.html I have no idea why my CSS wont show!!!!

Comment: link in HTML is link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css href="{{ STATIC_URL}}/base.css" /

Comment: Did you try to check whether your css file loads on page or not? Using Firebug etc.

Comment: What happens when you point your browser directly to the css file? Do you see it?

Comment: @WesleyMurch how do i point my browser directly to the file?

Comment: @user1957076: Well, you put the URL of the file in the address bar of your browser and hit "enter"...

Comment: all i see is what i wrote in the file: body {background-color:yellow} in text form

Answer (score 1):

`type="text/css` needs a closing quotation mark, like this: `type="text/css"`